# TFS 2015 Command Line build task fails after executing xUnit tests but there's no error/issue

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, nunit, tfs-2015, xunit

In the build definition in TFS 2015, I've got a Command Line step that runs the following command:

```
xunit.console.exe \PathToTests\Tests.dll -xml \PathToResultsFolder\Results.xml
```

During the build, I can see the tests are being discovered and executing and everything's looking good.

But if I don't check "***Continue on error***" in the Command Line step, after the tests run and the result XML file has been saved, the step fails with the following error:

> Task CmdLine failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

But there's actually no error or anything I can see. The tests have run and the XML file has saved properly and is able to published to TFS. And I don't see an error like this if I run the command from the build machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and post the detail log here.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I set debug to true and there is no other error in the entire log. It just added 1 more line of info to the error I mentioned above: `##[error]System.Exception: Task CmdLine failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
 
2017-12-17T21:50:18.6167696Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)`

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? You can share a simple sample on the OneDrive, also share the detail log too.

Comment: You may share a simple sample on the OneDrive.

Comment: I guess the output code from xunit.console.exe should be a non 0 code for a successful run. Can you get the exit code of the console run?

Comment: You can check whether the log contains exit code. (set system.debug to true)